# Changing Symfony's Template to Jade?

Tags: php, symfony, pug

So I am very new to Symfony, but after just getting my head around the set up issues I add with my config and .htaccess files, it seems like a very good framework.

Now I am coming from a CakePHP background, which I still use but I have a few person projects on right now and wanted to explain my knowledge to Symfony and Laravel.

So when reviewing these frameworks, found that they use different template systems/engines (Twig and Blade). And I have always wanted to use .Jade template but never got around to it. And now fought that it might be (?) a good idea to switch to just using one template system.

So my question is, as I can not seem to find a answer to it anywhere, can I use Jade templates with Symfony and Laravel?

Also is it wise to do so? I know that Symfony can be switched to using PHP rather than Twig but nothing else seems to be on there documentation that I could find.

Thanks,

Comment: http://www.sitepoint.com/introduction-jadephp/, https://github.com/everzet/jade.php

Comment: Yes I did know about Jade PHP but its not been updated in a while (5 years ?). So I was thinking about Grunt setting that up to run the compile to HTML but not sure how to add this into any framework? I guesting this is just not the best action to take and to use what the framework gives